# TinyMCE not loading HTML dymanically from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using Ajax to load content dynamically into my TinyMCE Editor which is setup on page load, a user will click a button to load in content (HTML) and then I use:

```
var notes = response["notes"];
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(notes);
```

To load in the raw HTML which has been filtered server side, all content is filtered through HTML Purifier setting which tags I want to allow.

This is what I get in the editor:
[image]

Now I know its not the server sides fault because I tried outputting the notes directly and the HTML renders on page load, but when it is past using Ajax it does that?

Upon receiving the Ajax response I do run it through `response = JSON.parse(response);` as the response is an array, sure that should not cause any problems?

If I do an alert on the response right away, before doing anything with the Ajax response I get this:
[image]

As you can see in the notes element, the HTML is being filtered by something? Is it chrome?, it does this in FF as well?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, database input was getting filtered first.